# Issues with posting data to MongoDB via taxii server (medallion)

Tags: python, mongodb, alienvault

I am using medallion implementation of taxii (https://github.com/oasis-open/cti-taxii-server) to connect with OTX (https://github.com/AlienVault-OTX/OTX-Apps-TAXII). However, I seem to be getting this error on the taxii server.

127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jun/2018 11:25:57] "POST /taxii HTTP/1.1" 405 -

Here's my configuration file

```
server_ip=127.0.0.1:5000
username=admin
password=Password01
discovery_path=/taxii/
collection_name=alienvaultotx
uri=/taxii/
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the meaning of http response code = 405?

Comment: @dkb yes i do. Response code 405 is method not allowed.

Comment: So check signature of API, are you missing any mandatory parameter while calling api, API documentation will be helpful

Comment: @dkb <api-root>/collections/<id>/objects/

GET, POST

object* 
 this is what is shown in the documentation but i do not have a collection nor an api root created